# Rails view unable to display form input parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to build a form that has an input for a question, and five inputs, each of which represents an answer choice.

My problem is that in my `/show.html.erb` file, it throws an error which I can't figure out.

For instance:

```
QUESTION
ANS1
ANS2
ANS3
ANS4
ANS5
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
# app/views/mcqs/new.html.erb
<%= form_for :mcq, url: mcqs_path do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :q %>

    <%= f.label :ans1 %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :ans1 %>

    <%= f.label :ans2 %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :ans2 %>

    <%= f.label :ans3 %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :ans3 %>

    <%= f.label :ans4 %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :ans4 %>

    <%= f.label :ans5 %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :ans5 %>


    <%= f.label :category_id %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :category_id %>

  <%= f.label :tags %><br>
    <%= collection_check_boxes(:mcq, :tag_ids, Tag.all, :id, :name) %>

    <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

The controller:

```
# app/controllers/mcqs_controller.rb
class McqsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @Mcq = Mcq.new
    end

    def index
        @questions = Mcq.all
    end

    def show
        @Mcq = Mcq.find(params[:id])    
    end

    def create
        @Mcq = Mcq.new(params[:mcqs])
        # @Mcq.save returns a boolean indicating whether the article was saved or not.
        if @Mcq.save 
            redirect_to @Mcq
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end
end
```

The view:

```
# app/news/mcqs/show.html.erb
<strong>MCQ Title:</strong><br>
<%= mcq.q %>

<strong>Question Text:</strong><Br>
<%= mcq.ans1 %>

...<strong>MCQ Title:</strong><br>
<%= mcq.q %>

<strong>Question Text:</strong><Br>
<%= mcq.ans1 %>
...
```

The error:

```
NameError in Mcqs#show
Showing app/views/mcqs/show.html.erb where line #4 raised:

undefined local variable or method `mcq' for #<#
<Class:0x007fad811936e8>:0x007fad838a47a0>

<strong>MCQ Title:</strong><br>
<%= mcq.q %>
</p><p>
```

How can I display the input of the `new.html.erb` on the `show.html.erb` without this error?. `<%= @mcq.q %>` doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `show` method you create `@Mcq` as  `Mcq.find(params[:id])`, but then in your `show` view you want to access to it as `mcq`, so you need to access it the same way (name) as you declared it within the controller.

Try with:

```
<strong>MCQ Title:</strong><br>
<%= @Mcq.q %>
```

If you create a `@mcq` on the controller (`show` method), and then you want to access to it in the view which responds to that method using `@Mcq`, then you will receive an object with `NilClass`, that's to say, if the names don't match, they won't work.

Also if you use `@mcq` on the controller, and then you want to access as `mcq`, that won't work neither, the one on your controller is an instance variable, available to be used within your views coming from your controllers, the second one is a local variable, and most probably it'll raise an `undefined local variable or method 'variable'` error.

I can quote to @Anhubaw with:

> The main difference between local and instance variable is that local
>   variable is only available in controller, where as instance variable
>   is available in corresponding views also. The controller and views do
>   not share local variables

Comment: Can you explain the difference between @Mcq and mcq? The @ sign and the capilations differences? Why does it matter?

Comment: I updated the answer @mazing, try also yourself to see the differences.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! :)

Answer (score 1):

Change all `@Mcq` in controller to `@mcp`, and change all `mcq` in view to `@mcq`, also change `:mcq` in new view to `@mcq`.

The variable prefix with `@` means it is an instance variable, it can be accessible in the view, while the normal variable doesn't start with `@` is just a local variable, it just can be used in the controller action method.

Comment: That did not work, the show field is just showing a blank result now. thank you though!